# Android: Having trouble working with Camera source code

Tags: android, eclipse, git, camera

I've written a camera app using SurfaceView that is doing what I want it to do...however, I'm finding myself replicating more and more of the native camera features, and I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel...so I used GIT to pull down the camera source, thinking I should start here and add my classes and code to it.  I checked licensing, and I am allowed to use the source, and can freely distribute my modified executable, etc.

My problem:
I pulled down the source, it landed in a Camera folder off of the root, and when I try to import it into my workspace with Eclipse (latest), it's only finding a test project, and not pulling it all in.

So...I created a new project, and imported from filesystem into the open project, and I have tons of errors.  Not worth debugging, I'm obviously missing something important in concept.

My question: what is the correct procedure to pull down this app, and get it running on my local machine?  I'm willing to bet there's a fairly simple answer, but not having any luck finding it (not searching correctly or something...)

THANK YOU ALL IN ADVANCE!  :)  I appreciate the help.

Mark

Answer (score 2):

The Android Open Source Camera is not really meant to be built as an Android Project in Eclipse, it uses system libraries that are not readily available to us and permissions that assume it is a system app.

You can use makefiles to generate the apk, but then you'd need almost all of the AOSP project.

Answer (score 0):

The AOSP Camera app has very ancient legacy, and that's why it is hard to build it standalone. Some efforts were successful, though, e.g. https://github.com/lightbox/QuickSnap

You can spring off some other project, like [Focal](https://github.com/xplodwild/android_packages_apps_Focal). Consider also [CWAC-Camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) project, which provides an easy-to-use API for your app. You can see an example of an app that uses this library [on GitHub](https://github.com/purirohan/AndroidCamera-CWAC-).

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into both. My app is working, I just need to add a few more features, but I thought I could tap into all the extras for free.  :)